# Running method continiously inside Main

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have two integers; start and stop
Initially start is 0 and stop is 1. Once the user closes the window start becomes 1.

I have a method which updates my JTable;

```
private void Update_table(){


 try{
   String sql ="select * from orders  ";
   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs=pst.executeQuery();
   Table_Employee.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


 }
 catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

 }

}
```

I want to update the table continuously but When I put a while loop inside the void main method the program crashes;

void main;

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

            //Update_table();
  while(start<stop)
      new Employee_info().Update_table();


    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Employee_info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Employee_info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Employee_info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Employee_info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Employee_info().setVisible(true);
         //   while(1<2)
           // rh.Update_table();
           // Update_table();
        }
    });
}
```

The erro;

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQL SyntaxErrorException: User 12345 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

Where 12345 is the user name to connect to the database, is it because I login to the database in different classes and run queries as well?

connection class;

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class javaconnect {
Connection conn=null;

    public static Connection ConnecrDb(){
      try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXX.com:3306/XXX_pizza","12345 ","XXXX");
    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got connected");
              return conn;

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
}      

}
}
```

The Employee_Info class calls to javaconnect class to make a connection;

```
public Employee_info() {
    initComponents();
    conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
    Update_table();

}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Just added error to the original question.

Comment: How are connections managed? More than likely, you're doing something wrong with allocating connections.

Comment: Just added the javaconnect class

Comment: Is there a way to terminate connection at the end of the Upload_Table method?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things:

1) In a while loop like that, you should probably call Thread.sleep() at some point.
2) In this case, because you're not sleeping and getting a new connection every time you call the `Employee_info` constructor, you're creating lots of connections, that's likely the direct cause of your error.
3) You shouldn't have a business object like `Employee_info` make the connection. Instead, you should have a tier in between (usually called a data access layer), with something like this:

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    public Employee_info getEmployeeInfo(){
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        //do something with the connection, construct employee info
        return employeeInfo
    }
}
```

4) You should use a connection pool, instead of instantiating connections by hand. Commons-dbcp is a used, erm, commonly.

5) Follow Java naming conventions.